# Insert rows into SQL Server database periodically

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me the best practice to insert data into a SQL Server database periodically? Say once a day. I get data once in a day from an external source such as a `.csv` file.

Are there any service programming api that SQL Server supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're not using SQL Express you can create an SSIS package to do the import, or a `BULK LOAD` or something like that, and then run the import once a day using a SQL Agent job that uses a daily schedule.

You could also create a Windows Scheduled Task.  The task could run a script that connects to SQL Server and runs an SSIS Package, a `BULK LOAD`, etc.  It could also execute a custom program that loads the data.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input.